# blank screen emulator displaying in android studio

Tags: android

i have downloaded the below packages
[EXTRAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgBoy.png)

[API 27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8fw3.png)

[TOOLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQqSX.png)

But i am getting
[BLANK SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2gFO.png) on emulator startup

[my avd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Yth.png)

Comment: Show me the code here in your xml?

Comment: i dont have code just trying to create an avd through sdk manger

Comment: But in title you mentioned in Android Studio?

Comment: emultor, avd manager,sdk manger is part of android studio only

Answer (score 0):

The "Use Host GPU" does only works with Android 4.2 as "Target".

So uncheck it to make it work.

And also turn off front and back camera's as it is emulator.

Comment: stil blank screen is there even after unchecking .. am i missed downloading any packages

Comment: Did you turned off camera?

Comment: after turning off camera its still showing blank screen

Comment: Starting emulator for AVD 'nexus'
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0xc0000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/Users/clark/.AndroidStudio/config/options/updates.xml"
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554

Comment: Your RAM size is too high i.e., 1536 make it 1024 OR 768 and try